# Where is the following code for plotting decision surface hanging?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mesh, freeze

As an exercise, I copy-pasted the decision-surface plotting code from the sklearn docs on the iris dataset:

```
# Few differences from the original at the link below (two classes, some renamed vars):
# http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_iris.html
# Parameters
n_classes = 2
plot_colors = "rb"
plot_step = 0.02

# Get my X and y - each sample is a histogram with a binary class label.
X, y, positives = Loader.load_cluster_size_histograms_singular(m=115, upper=21, norm=False, display_plot=False, pretty_print=False)

my_features = [str(i+1) for i in range(X.shape[1])]
my_features[-1] = my_features[-1] + '+'
features = np.asarray(my_features)

# Load iris data
iris = load_iris()

iris.data = iris.data[:, 100]
iris.target = iris.target[:, 100]

features = iris.feature_names  # Comment or uncomment as necessary

# Now asserting that my X and y does not contain np.nan or np.inf (wouldn't sklearn catch this though?)
# Also check for correct sizing. We're really running out of potential failures here.
for i in range(115):
    assert(np.nan not in X[i])
    assert(np.inf not in X[i])
    assert(X[i].shape[0] == 21)

# They do not. X and y are clean.

for pairidx, pair in enumerate([[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3],
                                [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]):
    # Set local_X = X[:, pair], local_y = y, features to my_features... BOOOOOM! 
    # CPU gets nuked, doesn't terminate.
    local_X = iris.data[:, pair]
    local_y = iris.target

    # Train
    clf = Pipeline(steps=[("scaling", StandardScaler()), ("classifier", LogisticRegression(verbose=100))])
    clf.fit(local_X, local_y)

    # Plot the decision boundary
    plt.subplot(2, 3, pairidx + 1)

    x_min, x_max = local_X[:, 0].min() - 1, local_X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = local_X[:, 1].min() - 1, local_X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, plot_step),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, plot_step))
    plt.tight_layout(h_pad=0.5, w_pad=0.5, pad=2.5)

    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    cs = plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu)

    plt.xlabel(features[pair[0]])
    plt.ylabel(features[pair[1]])

    # Plot the training points
    for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), plot_colors):
        idx = np.where(local_y == i)
        plt.scatter(local_X[idx, 0], local_X[idx, 1], c=color, label=features[i],
                    cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, edgecolor='black', s=15)

plt.suptitle("Decision surface of a decision tree using paired features")
plt.legend(loc='lower right', borderpad=0, handletextpad=0)
plt.axis("tight")
plt.show()
```

With the following output:

[image: iris data decision surface]

Okay? So the code is completely fine, just renamed and using/removing some tiny bits and bobs. Absolutely no problems here.

My problem is this - when I substitute the iris dataset with my own, it completely grenades the CPU at the line `clf.fit(local_X, local_y)`. Doesn't matter what classifier, Logistic Regression, SVM, GaussianNB, the lot. Everything slows down to an unbelievably slow crawl and it takes dozens of seconds for a click to register. Doesn't terminate, even after several minutes of hearing my CPU get waterboarded. The **ONLY** difference in the above code is that I set `local_X = X[:, pair]`, I set `local_y = y`, and I set `features = np.asarray(my_features)` (where my_features is my own feature name vector as a numpy array).

A visual of the CPU load on a Macbook Air with a 1.4 GHz Intel Core i5:

[image: CPU load after running on own dataset]

My dataset is not exactly huge either - just (115, 21) and (115,) for my own X and y. So the size of the data cannot be a factor.

Now some Q/A for those people on SO that like criticising and not helping:

*You're not scaling your inputs.*

- False. That is literally the first stage in my pipeline. I will say that my feature vector is a histogram though. I have tried instead to scale by having each histogram sum to 1. Exact same problem.

*You're doing it wrong.*

- Outstanding observation. Would you mind explaining what I am doing wrong, exactly?

*Have you tried turning it off and on again?*

- How would that help? And yes, I have, despite the total lack of rationale as to why I should. I've restarted the kernel, new session. Same problem.

When I run the code on mine with verbosity of the classifier set to 100, the only output I get is this:

`[LibLinear]`

Not very much, but it's all it prints. Appreciate any helpful comments, suggestions, and ideally answers!

EDTI:

Have been asked for a representative sample of my dataset. As stated, the samples are histograms. An example might look like this (of type np.array with elements of type np.float32):

```
[1515. 1072.  598.  447.  307.  221.  184.  166.  121.   82.   76.   67.   69.   58.   39.   49.   40.   37.   24.   27.  590.]
```

UPDATE: So having tried loading my dataset again with `norm=True` (meaning each histogram is summed to 1 so my float values are between 0 and 1, but no other normalisation takes place, this is without StandardScaler() in the pipeline), the code runs, but gets a useless result:

[image: result for when norm=True, no StandardScaler()]

For when StandardScaler() is included in the pipeline, I get similarly weird results when using Logistic Regression:

[image: results for when norm=True, StandardScaler() included]

The complete hanging still occurs when norm=False. This is quite bizarre.

Comment: Can you share your dataset? If not, are there any unusual elements in your data such as inf or NaN? Can you post your code, and show how you're replacing the Iris dataset with your own data?

Comment: @troymyname00 Have manually checked and used assert as indicated above - the answer is no, the dataset is clean. Could use ints in my case, but that absolutely should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out the problem - it wasn't actually the `fit()` function breaking. It was `np.meshgrid()`! It was the fact that the `plot_size` parameter was set to 0.02 when the range of the inputs was in the hundreds or thousands.

My guess is that when `np.meshgrid()` is called with the range of values, the sheer number of coordinates causes it to go completely berserk. Once I started using values that were more reflective of sensible steps (e.g. 100) for my inputs it started working.

Pretty silly that `np.meshgrid()` doesn't throw a warning with these kinds of inputs. The amount of load on my CPU reached 475% at one point thanks to the lack of a heads-up. Likewise the sklearn docs could probably mention that the `plot_step` parameter should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Then please edit your question, and eliminate the wrong diagnosis and all the unnecessary code. You could have diagnosed where it was hanging with a simple print statement, As stands, this is not a reusable resource.